# Custom keyboard on alert dialog

Tags: android, keyboard, android-alertdialog, custom-keyboard

Actually i have created custom keyboard for my application. It's working absolutely fine on every screen all the activities, but I don't know how to set custom keyboard on alert dialog.

I am using below code to call keyboard in activities:

```
    UserPayAmount.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            customFractionalKeyboard= new CustomFractionalKeyboard(VendorPaymentActivity.this, R.id.keyboard_number, R.xml.fractional_keyboard);

            customFractionalKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.VendorPayAmount);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

[trying to create keyboard on this dialog, above buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlyrf.png)

Comment: I guess i have attached wrong image .I want to create keyboard on background image .

Comment: problem solved ....

Comment: how you solve the problem?

Comment: that I need to check in my old code..

Comment: bdw I developed different keyboard application

Comment: My custom keyboard still not working on the dialog

Comment: ok ..I'll find the code and give it to u